# Using PowerShell, unprotecting an Excel workbook functions correctly, but a worksheet does not

Tags: excel, powershell

As the title says, I can unprotect the workbook but not the worksheet. What am I missing?

Here's the code:

```
$WorkBook = $objExcel.workbooks.Open($_.FullName,0,1) #Path, UpdateLinks, Readonly, Format, Password
$QuoteSheet = $WorkBook.Sheets.Item(1)
$objExcel.AutomationSecurity = 'msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable'
$msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable=3
$WorkBook.unprotect("xxxx") <-- works
$QuoteSheet.unprotect("xxxx") <-- doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my workbook was opening to the second worksheet and not the first. While the pride in me would like to see this deleted, an example for how to unprotect workbooks and worksheets using PowerShell should be helpful to others in the future as Google has a hard time finding any.